# ValueError: too many values to unpack (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping

So this is pretty much a web scraping program. I feel as if it is nearly finished, but I have no clue how to fix this!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AgriMet4.py", line 424, in <module>
    orig_column = convert(station, webpage, data_type)
  File "AgriMet4.py", line 244, in convert
    ag_date, ag_time, ag_data_str = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here are the parts that are flagged:

```
     # Break line into components
        ag_date, ag_time, ag_data_str = line.split()
        ag_datetime = ag_date + " " + ag_time
        ag_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(ag_datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
        ag_data = float(ag_data_str)
```

and

```
columns = []
for data_type in data_types:
    webpage = download(station, data_type, effective_begin_date, effective_end_date)
    orig_column = convert(station, webpage, data_type)
    std_column = fill_gaps(orig_column, interval, data_type,
                           effective_begin_date, effective_end_date)
    adjusted_column = adjust_datetimes(station, time_zone_offset, std_column)
    columns.append(adjusted_column)
```

EDIT: I've made the code shorter. Sorry!

Comment: Well, try printing `line.split()` to see what it's returning.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Dannnno Don't be sorry, this is my fault.

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, there are too many values on the right hand side of your equation (line.split()).

You can find the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for string splitting. You seem to have more than 3 values to assign. If you don't know how many values you will get, you can use the `*` syntax to hold any remaining values.

```
line = "Hello there world"
word1, *remaining_words = line.split()
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but I'm working with Python 2.6.8, maybe I should just try with a later version. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my problem!

My download definition had the incorrect data_types, which caused it to gather all six-seven data types at once instead of one at a time.

```
def download(station, data_types, begin_date, end_date):

    query_string = ('station=' + station
        + '&year='  + str(begin_date.year)
        + '&month=' + str(begin_date.month)
        + '&day='   + str(begin_date.day)
        + '&year='  + str(end_date.year)
        + '&month=' + str(end_date.month)
        + '&day='   + str(end_date.day)
        + '&pcode=' + data_types)
    url = AGRIMET_WEBSITE + '?' + query_string
```